# Normal force increasing with bank angle explanation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I've been told that as the bank angle increases the frictional force decreases and the normal force increases to preserve the net force (centripetal). However, I'm not sure how to explain how this happens in a more in-depth sense of physics.

Why friction becomes less the higher it goes and why the normal force increases?

All the websites don't give much of an explanation just siting what I said above.

thanks for the help,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because friction is always parallel to the bank surface and a normal force is always perpendicular to it.

Imagine the extreme scenarios:

- With the bank being flat (no banking), $\theta=0$, a normal force would point straight up and wouldn't be aiding to the horizontal centripetal force that causes turning.
- With the bank being vertical, $\theta=90^\circ$, the friction can only be vertical and thus can't aid in providing the horizontal centripetal force.

At any angle in between, both forces contribute a little to the horizontal centripetal force. The steeper the bank, the larger the normal force and smaller the friction.

Comment: I think I understand. The normal force acts perpendicular to the bank surface. Therefore the higher the incline the more the force points to the centre of the circle and aids in the overall net force. Opposite for parallel.

Comment: Plus thank you for your help, I'd upvote you if I could but my credit is too low. So enjoy your day

Comment: @CT-27-3555 No problem, you too